# how to shrink / normalize an SVG so it fits in a specific viewbox

Tags: svg

I used dozens of SVGs in my current app, they are all inline and they are all normalized.. meaning that all of them have a viewbox of 0 0 24 24 and the icon fits nicely in the middle

Then this designer just gave me multiple new SVGs and they are not standard.. they have viewboxes of 0 0 1024 1024, 0 0 400 400, 0 0 72 72

I want to normalize them so they all have a viewbox of 0 0 24 24.

I tried opening them in vectr.com and I united the paths and then shrunk them and exported the SVG again and sure enough they are much smaller now, however they do not fit 0 0 24 24 exactly.. I need to trial and error it and for example the 0 0 1024 1024 is now 0 0 48 40

I'm sure there's an editor / tool that could have done a perfect job of shrinking it and centering it in such a way that it would fit 0 0 24 24

How can I go about achieving this easily and simply?

Thank you

Comment: Why would you bother to do that?

Comment: Because in my vue project I made a re-usable icon component which accepts an inline svg path and defaults to a viewbox of 0 0 24 24. I use this dozens of times throughout the web app, and these new svgs all requiring different viewboxes is adding unwanted complexity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would have never thought of such a use case, but if you have exactly one path as the svg content, my own library [pathfit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pathfit) can rewrite the the path in that way. Here is a node.js script:

```
const Pathfit = require('pathfit');

function shrinkPath (path, viewBox, targetWidth, targetHeight) {
    const pathfitter = new Pathfit({viewBox}, undefined, path);

    return pathfitter.scale_with_aspect_ratio(targetWidth, targetHeight);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Works perfectly! It took me a while to figure out that I need to pass it the original viewbox and then the targetWidth and targetHeight should be the last two values of the desired viewbox.. but once I realized that it works perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do such a thing. But if you must, you may change the svg with a different viewBox in a `<symbol>` and use the symbol in an svg with the desired viewBox.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<symbol id="c" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
   <circle r="190" fill="red" cx="200" cy="200"/>
</symbol>
   <use xlink:href="#c" width="24" height="24" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Runnable snippet using @ccprog's answer. Paste in an SVG and enter the desired viewbox dimension and press submit.

```js
const textarea = document.getElementById('svg_textarea');
const dimensionInput = document.getElementById('dimension_input');
const output = document.getElementById('output');
const outputImage = document.getElementById('output_image')

function resize(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  try {
    // parse svg markup
    const template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML = textarea.value;
    const svg = template.content.querySelector('svg');

    // get viewbox
    const {
      x,
      y,
      width,
      height
    } = svg.viewBox.baseVal;
    const viewBox = `${x} ${y} ${width} ${height}`;

    // get path
    const path = template.content.querySelector('svg path');
    let d = path.getAttribute('d');

    // scale
    const dim = dimensionInput.valueAsNumber;
    const pathfitter = new Pathfit({
      viewBox
    }, undefined, d);
    d = pathfitter.scale_with_aspect_ratio(dim, dim);

    // output
    const markup = `<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 ${dim} ${dim}">
<path d="${d}" />
</svg>`;
    output.textContent = markup;
    outputImage.src = `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,${encodeURI(markup)}`;
    outputImage.hidden = false;
  } catch (err) {
    output.textContent = String(err?.stack ?? err);
  }
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', resize);

textarea.value = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
  <path d="M505.67 107.12 404.87 6.32a21.6 21.6 0 1 0-30.54 30.55l12.25 12.25-58.9 58.9-51.07-51.08a21.6 21.6 0 1 0-30.54 30.54l23.55 23.56L71.08 309.58a21.6 21.6 0 0 0 0 30.54l35.13 35.13-99.88 99.88a21.6 21.6 0 1 0 30.54 30.54l99.88-99.88 35.13 35.13a21.6 21.6 0 0 0 30.54 0l198.54-198.54 23.56 23.55a21.6 21.6 0 1 0 30.54-30.54l-51.07-51.08 58.9-58.9 12.24 12.26a21.6 21.6 0 1 0 30.54-30.55zM187.15 395.11l-70.26-70.26 28.52-28.51 18.32 18.32a21.6 21.6 0 0 0 30.54-30.54l-18.32-18.33 17.3-17.3 18.33 18.32a21.6 21.6 0 1 0 30.54-30.54l-18.32-18.33 17.3-17.3 18.33 18.32a21.6 21.6 0 1 0 30.54-30.54l-18.32-18.32 28.52-28.52 70.25 70.25-183.27 183.28zm186.3-241.34-15.22-15.22 58.9-58.9 15.21 15.23-58.9 58.9z"/>
</svg>`;
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 8px;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

textarea {
  padding: 8px;
}

output {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 8px;
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pathfit@1.0.4/pathfit.js"></script>

<form>
  <label for="svg_textarea">SVG Text</label>
  <textarea id="svg_textarea" rows="5"></textarea>

  <label for="dimension_input">Target viewbox width/height</label>
  <input id="dimension_input" type="number" min="1" step="1" value="16" />

  <button type="submit">Resize</button>

  <label for="output">Result</label>
  <output id="output"></output>

  <img id="output_image" alt="Output image" hidden />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Proportional scaling is actually quite simple:

1. parse the path's `d` attribute value to a pathData array
   – see `parseDtoPathData()` in example below.

```
[
    {type:"M", values:[0, 20]},
    {type:"L", values:[20, 32]}
    ...
]
```

I'm using the notation suggested by the `getpathData` working draft also used in [Jarek Foksa's polyfill](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill) – you can as well use this polyfill for parsing.

2. loop through all commands and multiply all x and y values by a scaling factor. We need to exclude `A` arcto command values for rotation (3.), long arc (4.) and sweep (5.) flag
   – `scalePathData()` .
   For proportional scaling we don't even need to normalize commands ( e.g. convert commands to all absolute; implicit or shorthand commands to explicit ones)

```js
/**
 * scale pathData
 */
function scalePathData(pathData, scale) {
  pathData.forEach((com) => {
    let {
      type,
      values
    } = com;

    switch (type.toLowerCase()) {
      case "a":
        com.values = [
          values[0] * scale,
          values[1] * scale,
          values[2], // rotation
          values[3], // long arc
          values[4], // sweep
          values[5] * scale,
          values[6] * scale
        ];
        break;

      default:
        if (values.length) {
          com.values = values.map(val => {
            return val * scale
          })
        }
    }
  });
  return pathData;
}



/**
 * parse pathData from d attribute
 **/
function parseDtoPathData(d) {
    let dClean = d
        // remove new lines and tabs
        .replace(/[\n\r\t]/g, "")
        // replace comma with space
        .replace(/,/g, " ")
        // add space before minus sign
        .replace(/(\d+)(\-)/g, "$1 $2")
        // decompose multiple adjacent decimal delimiters like 0.5.5.5 => 0.5 0.5 0.5
        .replace(/(\.)(?=(\d+\.\d+)+)(\d+)/g, "$1$3 ")
        // add new lines before valid command letters
        .replace(/([mlcsqtahvz])/gi, "\n$1 ")
        // remove duplicate whitespace
        .replace(/\ {2,}/g, " ")
        // remove whitespace from right and left
        .trim();

    // split commands
    let commands = dClean
        .split("\n")
        .map((val) => {
            return val.trim();
        });

    // compile pathData
    let pathData = [];
    let comLengths = {
        m: 2, a: 7, c: 6, h: 1, l: 2,
        q: 4, s: 4, t: 2, v: 1, z: 0
    };


    for (let i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
        let com = commands[i].split(" ");
        let type = com.shift();
        let typeRel = type.toLowerCase();
        let isRel = type===typeRel;

        // convert to numbers
        let values = com.map((val) => {
            return parseFloat(val);
        });

        /**
         * first M is always absolute/uppercase -
         * unless it adds relative linetos
         * (facilitates d concatenating)
         */
        if (i === 0) {
            type = "M";
        }

        /**
         * long arc and sweep flags 
         * are boolean and can be concatenated like
         * 11 or 01
         */
        if(typeRel==='a'){
            if (values.length < comLengths[typeRel]) {
                let lastFlag = values[values.length - 3].toString();
                if (lastFlag.length > 1) {
                   let flagArr = lastFlag.split("");
                   values = [ values[0], values[1], values[2] , +flagArr[0], +flagArr[1], values[4] , values[5] ];
                }
            }
        }

        // if string contains repeated shorthand commands - split them
        let chunkSize = comLengths[typeRel];
        let chunk = values.slice(0, chunkSize);
        pathData.push({ type: type, values: chunk });

        if(values.length>chunkSize){
            let typeImplicit = type === 'M' ? (isRel ? 'l' : 'L') : type;
            for (let i = chunkSize; i < values.length; i += chunkSize ) {
                let chunk = values.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
                pathData.push({ type: typeImplicit, values: chunk });
            }
        }

    }
    return pathData;
}

// pathData to d string
function pathDataToD(pathData, decimals = -1) {
  // implicit l command
  if (pathData[1].type === "l" && minify) {
    pathData[0].type = "m";
  }
  let d = `${pathData[0].type}${pathData[0].values.join(" ")}`;

  for (let i = 1; i < pathData.length; i++) {
    let com = pathData[i];
    
    // round
    if (decimals >= 0) {
      com.values = com.values.map((val) => {
        return +val.toFixed(decimals);
      });
    }
    d += `${com.type}${com.values.join(" ")}`;
  }
  return d;
}
```

```css
svg {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 80 80">
    <path d="
M 0 20.632 
H 500e-10 10 
v 5 5 
h 5 5 
V 38.632 40.632
h 5 5 
C30 46.632 35 50.632 40 50.632
c 0 5 5 10 10 10 
S 40 70.632 60 70.632                                 
q -23 -27 0 -20 
Q80 45.632 60 40.632
t-3-7 .001-15
A2 2.5 45 1 0 27 13.632
a 5 4 20 11 -10 -10.1 z
Z
" />
</svg>

<textarea id="svgMarkup"></textarea>

<script>
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {

    const svg = document.querySelector('svg')
    const decimals = 3;
    const newWidth = 24;

    // scale and show output
    scaleSVG(svg, newWidth);
    svgMarkup.value = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg)



    function scaleSVG(svg, newWidth, decimals = 3) {
      let {
        x,
        y,
        width,
        height
      } = svg.viewBox.baseVal;
      let scale = newWidth / width;

      // scale viewBox
      svg.setAttribute('viewBox', [x, y, width, height].map(val => {
        return +(val * scale).toFixed(decimals)
      }).join(' '))

      // scale children
      let els = svg.querySelectorAll('path')
      els.forEach(el => {

        // paths 
        if (el.nodeName === 'path') {

          // parse d to pathData
          let d = el.getAttribute("d");
          let pathData = parseDtoPathData(d);

          // scale and apply
          pathData = scalePathData(pathData, scale);
          el.setAttribute("d", pathDataToD(pathData, 3));
        }

        // polygons or polylines 
        else if (el.nodeName === 'polygon' || el.nodeName === 'polyline') {
          let points = el.points
          for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            points[i].x = +(points[i].x * scale).toFixed(decimals)
            points[i].y = +(points[i].y * scale).toFixed(decimals)
          }
        }
      })
    }


  })
</script>
```

3. stringify pathData array to `d` attribute value
4. scale `viewBox` values

#### Unproportional scaling

If you need to fit a svg in a viewBox with another aspect ratio you need some extra steps:

- Scale `h` and `v` commands seperately according to a x or y scaling factor
- if your path contains rotated elliptic arcs, you need to convert these to cubic béziers (See `normalizePathData()` in example below)

```js
/**
 * scale pathData
 */
function scalePathData(pathData, scaleX, scaleY) {
  pathData.forEach((com, i) => {
    let {
      type,
      values
    } = com;
    let typeRel = type.toLowerCase();

    switch (typeRel) {
      case "a":
        com.values = [
          values[0] * scaleX,
          values[1] * scaleY,
          values[2],
          values[3],
          values[4],
          values[5] * scaleX,
          values[6] * scaleY
        ];
        break;

      case "h":
        com.values = [values[0] * scaleX];
        break;

      case "v":
        com.values = [values[0] * scaleY];
        break;

      default:
        if (values.length) {
          for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i += 2) {
            com.values[i] *= scaleX;
            com.values[i + 1] *= scaleY;
          }
        }
    }
  });
  return pathData;
}




/**
 * parse pathData from d attribute
 **/
function parseDtoPathData(d) {
    let dClean = d
        // remove new lines and tabs
        .replace(/[\n\r\t]/g, "")
        // replace comma with space
        .replace(/,/g, " ")
        // add space before minus sign
        .replace(/(\d+)(\-)/g, "$1 $2")
        // decompose multiple adjacent decimal delimiters like 0.5.5.5 => 0.5 0.5 0.5
        .replace(/(\.)(?=(\d+\.\d+)+)(\d+)/g, "$1$3 ")
        // add new lines before valid command letters
        .replace(/([mlcsqtahvz])/gi, "\n$1 ")
        // remove duplicate whitespace
        .replace(/\ {2,}/g, " ")
        // remove whitespace from right and left
        .trim();

    // split commands
    let commands = dClean
        .split("\n")
        .map((val) => {
            return val.trim();
        });

    // compile pathData
    let pathData = [];
    let comLengths = {
        m: 2, a: 7, c: 6, h: 1, l: 2,
        q: 4, s: 4, t: 2, v: 1, z: 0
    };


    for (let i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
        let com = commands[i].split(" ");
        let type = com.shift();
        let typeRel = type.toLowerCase();
        let isRel = type===typeRel;

        // convert to numbers
        let values = com.map((val) => {
            return parseFloat(val);
        });

        /**
         * first M is always absolute/uppercase -
         * unless it adds relative linetos
         * (facilitates d concatenating)
         */
        if (i === 0) {
            type = "M";
        }

        /**
         * long arc and sweep flags 
         * are boolean and can be concatenated like
         * 11 or 01
         */
        if(typeRel==='a'){
            if (values.length < comLengths[typeRel]) {
                let lastFlag = values[values.length - 3].toString();
                if (lastFlag.length > 1) {
                   let flagArr = lastFlag.split("");
                   values = [ values[0], values[1], values[2] , +flagArr[0], +flagArr[1], values[4] , values[5] ];
                }
            }
        }

        // if string contains repeated shorthand commands - split them
        let chunkSize = comLengths[typeRel];
        let chunk = values.slice(0, chunkSize);
        pathData.push({ type: type, values: chunk });

        if(values.length>chunkSize){
            let typeImplicit = type === 'M' ? (isRel ? 'l' : 'L') : type;
            for (let i = chunkSize; i < values.length; i += chunkSize ) {
                let chunk = values.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
                pathData.push({ type: typeImplicit, values: chunk });
            }
        }

    }
    return pathData;
}


/**
 * serialize pathData array to
 * d attribute string
 */

function pathDataToD(pathData, decimals = -1, minify = false) {
  // implicit l command
  if (pathData[1].type === "l" && minify) {
    pathData[0].type = "m";
  }

  let d = `${pathData[0].type}${pathData[0].values.join(" ")}`;

  for (let i = 1; i < pathData.length; i++) {
    let com0 = pathData[i - 1];
    let com = pathData[i];

    let type =
      com0.type === com.type && minify ?
      " " :
      ((com0.type === "m" && com.type === "l") ||
        (com0.type === "M" && com.type === "l") ||
        (com0.type === "M" && com.type === "L")) &&
      minify ?
      " " :
      com.type;

    // round
    if (decimals >= 0) {
      com.values = com.values.map((val) => {
        return +val.toFixed(decimals);
      });
    }

    //type = com.type;
    d += `${type}${com.values.join(" ")}`;
  }

  d = minify ?
    d
    .replaceAll(" 0.", " .")
    .replaceAll(" -", "-")
    .replace(/\s+([A-Za-z])/g, "$1")
    .replaceAll("Z", "z") :
    d;
  return d;
}

/**
 * converts all commands to absolute
 * optional: convert shorthands; arcs to cubics
 */

function normalizePathData(pathData, unshort = true, convertArcs = false) {
  let pathDataAbs = [];
  let offX = 0;
  let offY = 0;
  let lastX = pathData[0].values[0];
  let lastY = pathData[0].values[1];

  pathData.forEach((com, i) => {
    let {
      type,
      values
    } = com;
    let typeRel = type.toLowerCase();
    let typeAbs = type.toUpperCase();
    let valuesL = values.length;
    let isRelative = type === typeRel;
    let comPrev = i > 0 ? pathData[i - 1] : pathData[0];
    let valuesPrev = comPrev.values;
    let valuesPrevL = valuesPrev.length;

    if (isRelative) {
      com.type = typeAbs;

      switch (typeRel) {
        case "a":
          com.values = [
            values[0],
            values[1],
            values[2],
            values[3],
            values[4],
            values[5] + offX,
            values[6] + offY
          ];
          break;

        case "h":
        case "v":
          com.values = type === "h" ? [values[0] + offX] : [values[0] + offY];
          break;

        case "m":
        case "l":
        case "t":
          com.values = [values[0] + offX, values[1] + offY];
          break;

        case "c":
          com.values = [
            values[0] + offX,
            values[1] + offY,
            values[2] + offX,
            values[3] + offY,
            values[4] + offX,
            values[5] + offY
          ];
          break;

        case "q":
        case "s":
          com.values = [
            values[0] + offX,
            values[1] + offY,
            values[2] + offX,
            values[3] + offY
          ];
          break;
      }
    }
    // is absolute
    else {
      offX = 0;
      offY = 0;
    }

    /**
     * convert shorthands
     */
    unshort = true;
    if (unshort) {
      let cp1X, cp1Y, cpN1X, cpN1Y, cp2X, cp2Y;

      if (com.type === "H" || com.type === "V") {
        com.values =
          com.type === "H" ? [com.values[0], lastY] : [lastX, com.values[0]];
        com.type = "L";
      } else if (com.type === "T" || com.type === "S") {
        [cp1X, cp1Y] = [valuesPrev[0], valuesPrev[1]];
        [cp2X, cp2Y] =
        valuesPrevL > 2 ?
          [valuesPrev[2], valuesPrev[3]] :
          [valuesPrev[0], valuesPrev[1]];

        // new control point
        cpN1X = com.type === "T" ? lastX + (lastX - cp1X) : 2 * lastX - cp2X;
        cpN1Y = com.type === "T" ? lastY + (lastY - cp1Y) : 2 * lastY - cp2Y;

        com.values = [cpN1X, cpN1Y, com.values].flat();
        com.type = com.type === "T" ? "Q" : "C";
      }
    }

    //convert arcs to cubics
    if (convertArcs && com.type === "A") {
      let p0 = {
        x: lastX,
        y: lastY
      };

      // add all C commands instead of Arc
      let cubicArcs = arcCommandToBezier(p0, com.values);
      cubicArcs.forEach((cubicArc) => {
        pathDataAbs.push(cubicArc);
      });
    } else {
      // add command
      pathDataAbs.push(com);
    }

    // update offsets
    lastX =
      valuesL > 1 ?
      values[valuesL - 2] + offX :
      typeRel === "h" ?
      values[0] + offX :
      lastX;
    lastY =
      valuesL > 1 ?
      values[valuesL - 1] + offY :
      typeRel === "v" ?
      values[0] + offY :
      lastY;
    offX = lastX;
    offY = lastY;
  });

  return pathDataAbs;
}

/**
 * convert Arcs to quadratic
 * or cubic beziers
 * recommended angle threshhold for quadratic: 22.5
 */
function arcCommandToBezier(
  p0,
  comValues,
  quadratic = false,
  angleThresh = 90,
  recursive = false
) {
  let [r1, r2, angle, largeArcFlag, sweepFlag, x2, y2] = comValues;
  let [x1, y1] = [p0.x, p0.y];
  const interpolate = (p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y, t) => {
    let pt = {
      x: (p2x - p1x) * t + p1x,
      y: (p2y - p1y) * t + p1y
    };
    return pt;
  };
  const degToRad = (degrees) => {
    return (Math.PI * degrees) / 180;
  };
  const rotate = (x, y, angleRad) => {
    let X = x * Math.cos(angleRad) - y * Math.sin(angleRad);
    let Y = x * Math.sin(angleRad) + y * Math.cos(angleRad);
    return {
      x: X,
      y: Y
    };
  };
  let angleRad = degToRad(angle);
  let params = [];
  let x, y, f1, f2, cx, cy, h;
  if (recursive) {
    f1 = recursive[0];
    f2 = recursive[1];
    cx = recursive[2];
    cy = recursive[3];
  } else {
    let p1 = rotate(x1, y1, -angleRad);
    x1 = p1.x;
    y1 = p1.y;
    let p2 = rotate(x2, y2, -angleRad);
    x2 = p2.x;
    y2 = p2.y;
    x = (x1 - x2) / 2;
    y = (y1 - y2) / 2;
    h = (x * x) / (r1 * r1) + (y * y) / (r2 * r2);
    if (h > 1) {
      h = Math.sqrt(h);
      r1 = h * r1;
      r2 = h * r2;
    }
    let sign = largeArcFlag === sweepFlag ? -1 : 1;
    let r1Pow = r1 * r1;
    let r2Pow = r2 * r2;
    let left = r1Pow * r2Pow - r1Pow * y * y - r2Pow * x * x;
    let right = r1Pow * y * y + r2Pow * x * x;
    let k = sign * Math.sqrt(Math.abs(left / right));
    cx = (k * r1 * y) / r2 + (x1 + x2) / 2;
    cy = (k * -r2 * x) / r1 + (y1 + y2) / 2;
    f1 = Math.asin(parseFloat(((y1 - cy) / r2).toFixed(9)));
    f2 = Math.asin(parseFloat(((y2 - cy) / r2).toFixed(9)));
    if (x1 < cx) {
      f1 = Math.PI - f1;
    }
    if (x2 < cx) {
      f2 = Math.PI - f2;
    }
    if (f1 < 0) {
      f1 = Math.PI * 2 + f1;
    }
    if (f2 < 0) {
      f2 = Math.PI * 2 + f2;
    }
    if (sweepFlag && f1 > f2) {
      f1 = f1 - Math.PI * 2;
    }
    if (!sweepFlag && f2 > f1) {
      f2 = f2 - Math.PI * 2;
    }
  }
  let df = f2 - f1;
  if (Math.abs(df) > (Math.PI * angleThresh) / 180) {
    let f2old = f2;
    let x2old = x2;
    let y2old = y2;
    f2 =
      sweepFlag && f2 > f1 ?
      (f2 = f1 + ((Math.PI * angleThresh) / 180) * 1) :
      (f2 = f1 + ((Math.PI * angleThresh) / 180) * -1);
    x2 = cx + r1 * Math.cos(f2);
    y2 = cy + r2 * Math.sin(f2);
    params = arcCommandToBezier({
        x: x2,
        y: y2
      }, [r1, r2, angle, 0, sweepFlag, x2old, y2old],
      quadratic,
      angleThresh, [f2, f2old, cx, cy]
    );
  }
  df = f2 - f1;
  let c1 = Math.cos(f1);
  let s1 = Math.sin(f1);
  let c2 = Math.cos(f2);
  let s2 = Math.sin(f2);
  let t = Math.tan(df / 4);
  let hx = (4 / 3) * r1 * t;
  let hy = (4 / 3) * r2 * t;
  let m1 = [x1, y1];
  let m2 = [x1 + hx * s1, y1 - hy * c1];
  let m3 = [x2 + hx * s2, y2 - hy * c2];
  let m4 = [x2, y2];
  m2[0] = 2 * m1[0] - m2[0];
  m2[1] = 2 * m1[1] - m2[1];
  if (recursive) {
    return [m2, m3, m4].concat(params);
  } else {
    params = [m2, m3, m4].concat(params);
    let commands = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i += 3) {
      r1 = rotate(params[i][0], params[i][1], angleRad);
      r2 = rotate(params[i + 1][0], params[i + 1][1], angleRad);
      r3 = rotate(params[i + 2][0], params[i + 2][1], angleRad);
      let cp1Q = interpolate(r3.x, r3.y, r2.x, r2.y, 3 / 2);
      if (quadratic) {
        commands.push({
          type: "Q",
          values: [cp1Q.x, cp1Q.y, r3.x, r3.y]
        });
      } else {
        commands.push({
          type: "C",
          values: [r1.x, r1.y, r2.x, r2.y, r3.x, r3.y]
        });
      }
    }
    return commands;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20em;
  max-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  border-color: transparent
}

svg {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px dotted #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grd {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1em;
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

[data-severity="severe"] {
  fill: red;
}

[data-severity="minor"] {
  fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="grd">

  <fieldset>

    <legend>Input</legend>
    <p>
      <label>width <input class="inputs" id="inputWidth" type="number" min="1" value="24" step="1"></label><br />
      <label>height <input class="inputs" id="inputHeight" type="number" min="1" value="16" step="1"></label><br />
      <label>Precision <input class="inputs" id="inputPrecision" type="number" value="3"></label>
    </p>

    <textarea class="inputs" id="svgInput">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 80 80">

                    <path d="
                M0 20.632 
                H 500e-10 10 
                v 5 5 
                h 5 5 
                V 38.632 40.632
                h 5 5 
                C30 46.632 35 50.632 40 50.632
                c 0 5 5 10 10 10 
                S 40 70.632 60 70.632                                 
                q -23 -27 0 -20 
                Q80 45.632 60 40.632
                t-3-7 .001-15
                A2 2.5 45 1 0 27 13.632
                a 5 4 20 11 -10 -10.1 z
                Z
                " />
                
                  </svg>

</textarea>

  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Output</legend>
    <textarea id="output"></textarea>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Preview</legend>
    <div id="preview"></div>
  </fieldset>

</div>

<script>
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
    let widthN = +inputWidth.value;
    let heightN = +inputHeight.value;
    let scaleX, scaleY;
    let decimals = +inputPrecision.value;
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".inputs");
    inputs.forEach((inp) => {
      inp.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
        let markup = svgInput.value;
        let svg;


        svg = new DOMParser()
          .parseFromString(markup, "text/html")
          .querySelector("svg");

        // reset preview
        preview.innerHTML = "";
        if (svg) {
          preview.appendChild(svg);
        }
        widthN = +inputWidth.value;
        heightN = +inputHeight.value;
        decimals = +inputPrecision.value;
        // get  bbox
        let {
          x,
          y,
          width,
          height
        } = svg.getBBox();
        scaleX = widthN / width;
        scaleY = heightN / height;
        // scale viewBox
        svg.setAttribute(
          "viewBox", [x * scaleX, y * scaleY, widthN, heightN].join(" ")
        );
        // scale children
        let paths = svg.querySelectorAll('path')
        paths.forEach(el => {
          // paths 
          if (el.nodeName === 'path') {
            let d = el.getAttribute('d');
            let pathData = parseDtoPathData(d);
            // normalize commands if scaling is unproportional
            if (scaleX !== scaleY) {
              pathData = normalizePathData(pathData, true, true);
            }
            // scale and apply
            pathData = scalePathData(pathData, scaleX, scaleY);
            let dScaled = pathDataToD(pathData, decimals, true);
            el.setAttribute("d", dScaled);
          }
        });
        let markupScaled = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
        output.value = markupScaled;
      });
    });
    svgInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
  })
</script>
```

#### Recommendations

- As commented: Usually, you don't need to scale/recalculate your `<path>` elements – changing the layout width/height via css is often enough
- Use cases for scaling: your svg is very small (e.g. based on geo data) or very huge (e.g. generated from CAD applications). So you might encounter rendering issues due to the browser's number limits – See ["The Limits of Numbers in SVG"](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch08-precision.html). You can also use this approach to create responsive `<clipPath>`s scaled to a 1x1 viewBox. See ["Clip Path SVG file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70864383/clip-path-svg-file/)
- Floating point accuracy: Small viewBoxes will also require an appropriate amount of decimals. In other words rounding coordinates to integers will most likely result in distortions when using small dimensions like 24x24 units

Testing: See [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/jOeRzRB) adding cropping feature